# How to create a projection from multi table

Tags: sql, projection, vertica

I have 2 tables as following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_employee
(
    index int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100),
    date_of_birth date,
    address varchar(100),
    id_dep int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT C_PRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (index) DISABLED
);


CREATE TABLE store.test_department
(
    index int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100),
    describe varchar(100),
    CONSTRAINT C_PRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (index) DISABLED
);
```

I need to create a projection with many columns from the above two tables, My current code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROJECTION public.employee_department_super  
(
 idEmp,
 idDep,
 empName,
 date_of_birth,
 address,
 depName,
 describe
)
AS
 SELECT e.index,
        e.id_dep,
         e.name,
         e.date_of_birth,
         e.address,
         d.name,
         d.describe
FROM
public.test_employee e 
inner join store.test_department d 
on e.id_dep=d.index 
ORDER BY e.name
UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;
```

But I received an error:

```
[Code: 9366, SQL State: 0A000]  [Vertica][VJDBC](9366) ROLLBACK: Projections must select data from only one table
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe to put current query into subquery? Something like this `... AS SELECT * FROM (your current query) AS a`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried as you said but I get this error: [Code: 5664, SQL State: 42601]  [Vertica][VJDBC](5664) ERROR: Subqueries not allowed in projection definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: you can't.

Join projections were a thing of a long gone past.

Vertica has begun to satisfy the need of reducing joins by the concept of the *flattened table*.

You add the two columns as *flattened columns* to your `test_employee` table, and they are automatically set whenever you insert new rows into the table.

```
ALTER TABLE public.test_employee
ADD depname VARCHAR(100) 
  DEFAULT(
    SELECT name FROM store.test_department d WHERE d.index=id_dep
  );

ALTER TABLE public.test_employee
ADD describe VARCHAR(100) 
  DEFAULT(
    SELECT describe FROM store.test_department d WHERE d.index=id_dep
  );
```

And the two flattened columns do not count against your license size.